# Inner Join when only one match exists

Tags: sql

Consider the following realistic scenario:

You have a table of towns, but want to lookup the respective zip
   codes of those towns.  In most cases, this is easy to do since there
   is only one zip code per town, but exceptions do apply when dealing
   with cities.

You have two tables:

```
CONTACT
Town          | Zip
--------------+----
Ft Washington | NULL
Ambler        | NULL
Media         | NULL
Ambler        | NULL
New York      | NULL

CITIES_EXTENDED
Town          | Zip
--------------+----
Ft Washington | 19034
Ambler        | 19002
Media         | 19063
New York      | 10101
New York      | 10102
New York      | 10103
New York      | 10104
```

With an `INNER JOIN` four rows would be returned for the `New York`.  This is obviously not desirable because that data is inherently inaccurate.

The desired result is as follows:

```
Town          | Zip
--------------+----
Ft Washington | 19034
Ambler        | 19002
Media         | 19063
Ambler        | 19002
New York      | NULL
```

What is the best way of achieving this goal?

Comment: Why is it "undesirable" and "inherently inaccurate" to return the 4 matching zip codes?

Comment: Please post the `CREATE TABLE` of the tables you are attempting to join.  So if there are multiples returned in the zip table, you want a `NULL` instead?

Comment: I agree with @MartinSmith, the set nature of SQL is that you normally want four rows for New York.

Comment: Is the desired result of this an `UPDATE` statement to fill in the `Zip` column as some kind of denormalisation? If so what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Martin The "Contact" table contains values for contacts and has other fields.  Consider that the returned result will be used to update the contact table.  In that case the four returned results is ambiguous and undesirable. Blank/NULL = unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Select  a.Town,
        b.zip
FROM    contact a
INNER JOIN cities_extended b ON a.Town = b.Town
WHERE a.Town NOT IN (
    SELECT  Town
    FROM    (
        Select  Town,
                COUNT(*)
        From    cities_extended
        Group by Town
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) T
)

UNION ALL 

Select  DISTINCT
        a.Town,
        NULL
FROM    contact a
INNER JOIN  cities_extended b ON a.Town = b.Town
WHERE   a.Town IN (
    SELECT  Town
    FROM    (
        Select  Town,
                COUNT(*)
        From    cities_extended
        Group by Town
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) T
)
```

See my [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcf87/25)

This may not be an elegant solution but this gets the job done as per your requirement ;-)

Comment: `All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.`

Answer (score 3):

Does this solve your problem?

```
select ce.Town, 
case when count(*) > 1 then null else Max(c.Zip) end as Zip
from CITIES_EXTENDED ce
    inner join CONTACT c
        on ce.Town = c.Town
    group by ce.Town
```

The Max() function will work just fine because you will only have one value for c.Zip.

Comment: Well, no.  The selection needs to be from the **CONTACT database so I can grab other information from CONTACT.**  Your solution is exactly how I would do it otherwise.

Comment: You can grab whatever you want from the CONTACT table as long as these fields are also listed in the group by.

Comment: But the end result is that the Zip in CONTACT will be updated.  That is why I wanted a select from CONTACT; so I could make it into an update.